# What's the difference between Physics2D.OverlapPoint and Physics.Raycast?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been looking at options to detect a clicked GameObject. For a 2D game, what is the difference between Physics2D.OverlapPoint and Physics.Raycast? Is there any advantage of one over the other, performance maybe? I get the same return value for both and both seem to have the same problems with overlapping sprites. I've been leaning towards using Physics.Raycast since I may want to move to a 3D to a top-down perspective in the future, any other considerations?

Comment: Anyone has metrics regarding performance on each for 2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OverlapPoint` checks if a collider overlaps a given point in space while `Raycast` shoots a ray along a specific vector and returns anything it hits.

Very different concepts and not to be used interchangeably... even in 2D.  You can fire a `Raycast` starting beyond your 2D scene and fire back toward the viewer (defined by the direction vector) or in front of the scene and fire away from the viewer.  Different results will be returned as they ray will hit different colliders depending on z-order.

Answer (score 2):

A picture is worth 1000 words:

Here is the raycasting:

[image]

Here is OverlapPoint, which checks if a collider overlaps a point in space.

[image]

Comment: Haha.. I love the overlap point picture.  You just drew that didn't you?  ;-)  That is a difficult one to 'draw' though I agree.

Answer (score 0):

`OverlapPoint` is basically a `Raycast` except with no depth to it. You are right about using the `Raycast` if you plan on going 3D in the future. Also the returns are different, where `Raycast` returns you a `bool` and `OverlapPoint` returns you a `Collider2D`

Comment: Thanks for the response, so, in terms of cost (CPU), they are both the same?

Comment: I would imagine that `OverlapPoint` would be much quicker, as `Raycasts` are known to be a bit much sometimes, and `Raycasts` can be calculated at a vast range of different pointed directions and lengths, whereas `OverlapPoint` simply takes a point in 2d space and sees whether or not another `2DCollider` intercepts it, much like `Rect.Contains(...)`